# How to animate UIView back to original frame after Pinch gesture

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, uiviewanimation

I have tried with animate view with frame. It animate back to original state.Navigation bar get hide/show on click view (tap gesture) added for that.

**Issue :: After pinch gesture applied there is scaling happen on View.On tapping view it get reset to frame where it scale.** Not getting why view frame get reset after tapping.

Adding code for reference

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var animateView: UIView!
    var originalFrame : CGRect = CGRect.zero

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        originalFrame = self.animateView.frame
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapView(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(recognizer:)))
        pinchGesture.delegate = self
        self.animateView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    }

    @IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = recognizer.view {
          view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
            print("Recogniser scale value::: \(recognizer.scale)")
          recognizer.scale = 1
        }
        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {
            let viewFrame = animateView.frame
            //CGRectEqualToRect(viewBound,viewFrame)
            print("----------------------------------------------")

            if originalFrame.contains(viewFrame) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                    UIView.setAnimationCurve(.easeIn)
                    self.animateView.frame = self.originalFrame
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func didTapView(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let isShow = self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden else {
            return
        }
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = !isShow
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

Storyboard setting

1. Take navigation controller
2. Attach another viewController
3. Add UIView and set frame (0,64,320,504)
4. Add constraints (Leading,Trailing,Top,Bottom)
5. Connect UIView to `animateView`

[image]

**Current Output**

1. Pinch View till it half size
2. It will animate to original frame
3. Tap on coloured view, view get in state of step-1

**Expected Output**

1. Pinch View till it half size
2. It will animate to original frame
3. Tap on coloured view, this need not be get resized. As described in current output

Comment: it is not clear what you want to happen after pinch is over. Do you want it to go back to how it initially was when view loaded?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri in question added current and expected behaviour.